# How to undefine class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Undefining a method in Ruby is pretty simple, I can just use `undef METHOD_NAME`.

Is there anything similar for a class? I am on `MRI 1.9.2`.

I have to undefine an ActiveRecord Model, run two lines of code, and restore the model back to its original form.

The problem is, I have an model `Contact` and I am using a company's API and it happens that they have some class called `Contact`, and changing my model name would be lot of work for me.

What can I do in this situation?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

```
class Foo; end
# => nil
Object.constants.include?(:Foo)
# => true
Object.send(:remove_const, :Foo)
# => Foo
Object.constants.include?(:Foo)
# => false
Foo
# NameError: uninitialized constant Foo
```

**EDIT** Just noticed your edit, removing the constant is probably not the best way to achieve what you're looking for. Why not just move one of the `Contact` classes into a separate namespace.

**EDIT2** You could also rename your class temporarily like this:

```
class Foo
  def bar
    'here'
  end
end

TemporaryFoo = Foo
Object.send(:remove_const, :Foo)
# do some stuff
Foo = TemporaryFoo
Foo.new.bar #=> "here"
```

Again, the trouble with this is that you'll still have the newer `Contact` class so you'll have to remove that again. I would really recommend name-spacing your classes instead. This will also help you avoid any loading issues

Comment: No, you would probably need to remove the `contact.rb` file from `$LOADED_FEATURES` and then reload it but that may have some side effects. I didn't notice your edit when I first wrote my answer so I've updated it. That said, you may be able to temporarily rename it.

Comment: how to temporary rename? I'll rename, run code and rename it back. that sounds good?

Comment: Check my update, again I don't recommend this approach but that's how it could be done

Answer (score 2):

In a similar situation - mocking a class used internally by another class I'm trying to test - I found this to be a workable solution:

```
describe TilesAuth::Communicator do
  class FakeTCPSocket
    def initialize(*_); end
    def puts(*_); end
  end

  context "when the response is SUCCESS" do
    before do
      class TilesAuth::Communicator::TCPSocket < FakeTCPSocket
        def gets; 'SUCCESS'; end
      end
    end
    after { TilesAuth::Communicator.send :remove_const, :TCPSocket }

    it "returns success" do
      communicator = TilesAuth::Communicator.new host: nil, port: nil, timeout: 0.2
      response = communicator.call({})
      expect(response["success"]).to eq(true)
      expect(response).not_to have_key("error")
      expect(response).not_to have_key("invalid_response")
    end
  end
end
```

I would have thought there would be a better way to do this - i.e. I couldn't see a way to pass in the desired return value for reuse - but this seems good enough for now. I'm new to mocking/factories, and I'd love to hear about any alternative methods.

Edit:

Ok, so not so similar after all.

I found a better way using RSpec mock, thanks to [an excellent explanation in the RSpec Google Group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rspec/0GiBxedf3Nk/OhKxHcN3Z28J):

```
context "with socket response mocked" do
  let(:response) do
    tcp_socket_object = instance_double("TCPSocket", puts: nil, gets: socket_response)
    class_double("TCPSocket", new: tcp_socket_object).as_stubbed_const
    communicator = TilesAuth::Communicator.new host: nil, port: nil, timeout: 0.2
    communicator.call({})
  end

  context "as invalid JSON" do
    let(:socket_response) { 'test invalid json' }

    it "returns an error response including the invalid socket response" do
      expect(response["success"]).to eq(false)
      expect(response).to have_key("error")
      expect(response["invalid_response"]).to eq(socket_response)
    end
  end

  context "as SUCCESS" do
    let(:socket_response) { 'SUCCESS' }

    it "returns success" do
      expect(response["success"]).to eq(true)
      expect(response).not_to have_key("error")
      expect(response).not_to have_key("invalid_response")
    end
  end
end
```