# How do I reset a class definition in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

How can I completely remove a class from memory in Ruby?

I have two files I'm working with:

```
# foo.rb
require 'expensive_library'

class Foo < ExpensiveLibrary::Plugin
   ...
end
```

and:

```
# foo_tests.rb
require 'foo'
require 'test/unit'

class foo_tests < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_foo_meets_spec_1
    ...
  end
  def test_foo_meets_deprecated_spec
    ...
  end
end
```

ExpensiveLibrary is expensive; it takes over 15 seconds to load. This is way too long to repeatedly run the tests during development (the rest of the test suite takes less than 1 second).

I have worked around the load time of the expensive library by starting Pry and writing a function that loads the two files and calls `Test::Unit:Autorunner.run`. This still has a 15 second pause in the first run of the tests, but subsequent test runs take less than 1 second each.

However, there are two problems:

1. Pry complains about all the methods on Foo and Foo_tests being redefined
2. when I remove a method from the source file, it remains defined in my test environment, generating spurious failures.

Based on other Stack Overflow questions (like "[How to undefine class in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503558/how-to-undefine-class-in-ruby)"), I have tried calling `Object.constants.remove(:Foo)` and `Object.constants.remove(:Foo_tests)`. I no longer get the method redefined errors, but now the autorunner runs the tests multiple times, including removed tests.

What I want is to run the modified tests without reloading ExpensiveLibrary. Undefining the test classes is the way I see to do it, but I don't know how. Other solutions might be better.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that what you're looking for is a preloader such as [Spork](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork), or even a more specific one like [rspec-preloader](https://github.com/victormours/rspec-preloader). When using a preloader, you will have to require your 'foo' file in a `spec/spec_helper.rb` file, which you probably already have:

```ruby
# spec/spec_helper.rb
require 'foo'

# ...
```

The `spec_helper` should load your entire app environment. Arguably, it's more expensive when running tests one at a time. But by using a preloader, you only have to require all the code *once*.

Answer (score 0):

OK, just spitballing here, because I'm not certain exactly what you're trying to, but have you tried `undef` or `undef_method`? They don't work directly on classes, but if you undef the methods that call the tests you don't want done maybe it will work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can hack with load paths ([Adding a directory to $LOAD_PATH (Ruby)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837123/adding-a-directory-to-load-path-ruby)).

- create some folder like `./tests/fake_implementations/`
- add it to $LOAD_PATHS
- add there file `expensive_library.rb` with some lightweight fake implementation of `ExpensiveLibrary`
- then `require 'expensinsive_library'` will load this file instead of the original one.