# How to undefine namespaced class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I can undefine Bar ([How to undefine class in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503558/how-to-undefine-class-in-ruby)), but how to undefine Foo::Bar ?

```
irb(main):266:0> Object.send :remove_const, :ActiveRecord::Base
TypeError: :ActiveRecord is not a class/module

irb(main):267:0> Object.send :remove_const, :"ActiveRecord::Base"
NameError: `ActiveRecord::Base' is not allowed as a constant name

irb(main):269:0> module ActiveRecord; Object.send :remove_const, :Base; end
NameError: constant Object::Base not defined
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Constants are defined in their respective parent module, with top-level constants being defined on the `Object` class.

Thus, `ActiveRecord::Base` is a constant(`Base`) which is defined on the `ActiveRecord` module. Now, in order to remove this constant, you have to call the `remove_const` method on the `ActiveRecord` module:

```
ActiveRecord.send(:remove_const, :Base)
```

Alternatively, you could also traverse the path directly from `Object`, i.e.

```
Object.const_get(:ActiveRecord).send(:remove_const, :Base)
```

Comment: Ok, I see that it works for Foo::Bar, but it doesn't for ActiveRecord::Base
`irb(main):001:0> ActiveRecord.send(:remove_const, :Base)
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Core::ClassMethods::Base` or
`irb(main):002:0> Object.const_get(:ActiveRecord).send(:const_delete, :Base)
NoMethodError: undefined method 'const_delete' for ActiveRecord:Module` Is that happens because ActiveRecord undefines :const_delete method?

Comment: Well, ActiveRecord is actually a rather complex thing. It includes other modules and heavily uses meta-programming. As such, it can be difficult to manipulate. As for the typo in my answer (the `const_delete`), I just fixed it.